# At loss on how to tackle this problem about linear tranformations and vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I am given this problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMAZr.jpg

I am unsure on how to even begin solving this problem, and I am also clueless as to what the asterisk (*) is representing. Could anyone give me any pointers?

any help is appriciated

Comment: Each $e_j^*$ is a linear map from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$, namely that one defined by $e_j^*((x_1,\ldots,x_n)) = x_j$. So, the star here means nothing special.

Comment: It is usually used to denote  the dual basis of a basis – here the standard basis, in the dual space of a vector space.

Comment: Thanks. Can any of you give me some pointers in how to solve this exercise?